# windbg find which method is taking time

Tags: windbg

I have a page which is taking time to load. It is possible to find which method is taking time using windbg?

Thanks

Comment: Not really. You need a profiler for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need a debugger. You need a profiler.

Comment: @kumar: There are a few, it has been asked here before. Search on SO, or Google, should provide plenty options, free and non-free.

Answer (score 0):

wt (Trace and Watch Data) will give you an instruction count over a function or instruction range. This won't give you time information, though, so if you're blocking on IO it won't be revealed here.

!runaway will let you know time used per thread, so that may narrow it down if this is systematic.

Finally, AMD CodeAnalyst is a free profiler that works great and will help you figure out exactly where in the system your time is being spent. Make sure to set the polling frequency to .1ms.